# CSS input:focus does not work in Visual studio

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

CSS input does not work in Visual studio

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>  
        input:focus
        {
            background-color:red
        }
    </style>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use **input:hover** , it works.

Similar code works outside VS:

see **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus**

Please note that I have 2 **asp** TEXT boxes on my form. But they are supposed to be input.

**More info**: this does not seem to be related to ASP server cotrols . I removed the asp text boxes and used a simple html input:

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
```

Still same issue.

Update: MY visual studio was set to run under Internet explorer( I used IE11). I changed it to use Chrome and now focus works.

So can this be a bug with Visual studio? because IE11 can correctly use focus when using the w3schools link (above).

Comment: When you say "CSS input does not **work** in Visual studio", what do you mean exactly?  Do you mean it doesn't behave the way you expect when you debug and it launches the page in a browser?  Or do you mean it doesn't behave the way you expect in the IDE designer?

Comment: See the link above. on focus text box color supposed to change to yellow. In VS it does not.

Comment: I pasted your code into a new page in VS2015, ran it (which opens it in a browser, IE11 in this case) and it worked great.

Comment: hmm, then this could  be a bug with VS2013. do you have 2013?

Comment: Hmm, I quickly set up a VS2013 project and added your code. Worked fine in my IE11 (and Chrome of course).